# Loop logic for using two lists in processing text in python

Tags: python, loops, parsing, text, logic

I am working on parsing a bunch of text files. Each file has sections I need to check and update if necessary.
I read each file and find the beginning of each section I am interested in. I put the line number of each section into a list and all lines into another list.

So I end up with, for example:

```
l1=[7, 23, 45, 67, 89, 111, 133, 155]
```

l2 has all the lines from the file

Lines I am interested in start at line number 7 and end at 22, start at 23 and end at 44 and so on.

I want to read lines 7 - 22, validate the content or update it and move on to the next one.

I am very new to programming and I can't make this work properly. Sometimes I get close, but it never really works right.

I tried two nested for loops, a for loop and while loop but to no avail.
I can keep track of the index in the outside loop, but the inner loop never really works well because the index and content lists are tied together.

I know this is an elementary problem, but I can't make it work.
I am also open to suggestions for any elegant solutions.
Thank you.

```
for i in range(len(Index)):
    j = i
    for j in range(Index[i+1]):
        tempList = Content[i: i+1]
        # do some validation here on the tempList
```

Comment: First, I recommend that you practice *incremental programming*: write a few lines of code; make sure those do what you want before you move on.  Next, "I can't make it work" is not a specific programming problem.  What you're asking is too broad for Stack Overflow: we work on focused problems, not general problem solutions.  To start out, you need to design your program.  Write pseudo-code, or make a flowchart, or whatever representation works for your thought processes.  You want to write a recipe for doing this the way you might do it by hand.

Comment: Once you have that figured out, write individual parts of the problem, a few lines at a time.  Write a loop that can walk through your list of line numbered and print out the range of lines you want to use.  Once that works, write an inner loop that can iterate through those line numbers.  Look up how to use list slices to support your coding.

Comment: Thank you for your response and I appreciate your time. I am not a programmer so all this is new to me. It makes perfect sense though and my next post will be much improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By iterating through l1, you already have the index that you need to refer to your data, so you don't need second loop. What you want to do is to refer to two sequential values in l1. I did this by calling `l1[i]:l1[i+1]`

```
import numpy as np    

l1 = [7, 23, 45, 67, 89, 111, 133, 155]
data = np.random.randint(0, 9, 155)  # Your data here

for i in range(len(l1)-1):
    templist = data[l1[i]:l1[i+1]]
    # validation here
```

I created an array of random data, but you will put yours there instead.

Comment: I was totally overthinking it. This is so simple. Thank you.